# Database structure for affiliate system

Tags: mysql, database, data-structures

I am creating an affiliate tracking system and am looking for the best database structure to use on mySQL for low load on the server.

There will be 1000 affiliates. Each affiliate will have stats per day.

I am thinking of this scenario. One main table for the affiliates:

**Affiliates**

```
id    affiliate_id    username    password    and so on (other affiliates details)
1     0000001         johndeer    password
```

... and creating a new table for each affiliate which will have store his statistics like this:

**Table name : affiliate-userid**

```
Date        Clicks    sales    sale_price    total_earned    bonus
12/12/12    45        2        20            40              0
12/13/12    12        3        20            60              0
```

So in this case each affiliate will have his own statistics table.

Is this correct or do I need to do something else?

Comment: Off-topic for SO; belongs on [dba.se]

Comment: thanks , i have moved question there.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Create two table

- Affiliates(af_id(pk),*) and
- Stats(stat_id(pk),af_id(fk),*)

Then, Refer Affiliates table in stats table. you can add any number of stats for any number of affiliates. No need to go for a table for each affiliate. It's a bad Idea.I think you understood.

Comment: but how can i add stats by per day and for each affiliate. thanks

Comment: Affiliate id is there for each stat in stats table and date column is already there in that table. so you can insert day in date column and respectively affiliate id will consists of the id of the affiliate generated in affiliates table.

Comment: There will be only one row for each affiliate in affiliate column, but many rows in stats column for each affiliate and per each day. upvote if you agree.

Comment: If you are using foreignkey relationships in your database go for InnoDB, It supports transactions, foreign key relationships and many more features..!